# Hibernate - OGM [PersistenceUnit: person] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

i am getting an below error

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: person] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:63)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>       at com.ihappyk.utility.Utility.setUpEntityManagerFactory(Utility.java:11)
>       at com.ihappyk.work.PersonWorker.main(PersonWorker.java:14)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.ihappyk.model.Person]
>       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:123)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:225)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:323)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unanticipated return type [java.lang.Long] for UUID conversion
>       at org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator.configure(UUIDGenerator.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:117)
>       ... 13 more

Utilty.java

```
public class Utility {
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    //@BeforeClass
    public static EntityManagerFactory setUpEntityManagerFactory() {
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "person" );
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    //@AfterClass
    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Persistant Class

```
@Entity
public class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
        private long id;

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public Person(){

        }

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }    
}
```

main class

```
public class PersonWorker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Utility.setUpEntityManagerFactory();

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

            // create a Person
        Person bob = new Person( "Bob", "McRobb" );

        em.persist( bob );
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }

}
```

persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="person" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
       <class>com.ihappyk.model.Person</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="hibernateOGM" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="127.0.0.1" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017" />
            <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: This belongs to `eclipse` project management. You should explicitly mark your `persistence.xml` to be added into build.

Comment: Ya i have configured it in the build path of the project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root exception says it all:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unanticipated return type [java.lang.Long] for UUID
```

You are using a UUID id generator on a type which it does not support. You should use `String` instead of `Long` in this case.

Comment: but this example was given on the links you provided.

Comment: its still the same , unable to build hibernateSession factory

Answer (score 1):

1. if you use this deprecated org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence set new provider like below

> `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`

2. if your value is

> `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />`

set "create-drop"

> `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />`

3. XML path: resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
4. For mysql

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
            <properties>
                  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
                  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
                  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="yourname"/>
                  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="yourpassword"/>
                  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourschema"/>
                  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should share your the complete stacktrace about the exception and the persistence.xml content. Then in my opinion based on what I see the problem could be that you don't have declared a persistence provider in your persistence.xml. In fact if you are developing in a non container managed envirorment you need to declare a persistence provider.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myunit" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    //Others properties
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if the problem still exists, but I thought you have to put the persistence.xml file into src/main/META-INF folder. I see you put it into src/META-INF. Maybe that is the Problem? and of course the entities you want to link belong in src/main folder, too :)

Comment: Just some tool like maven using a /src/main/..., in a plain java project this is a correct place.